# How to select five items that have most orders?(SQL QUERY)

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: 1]

How can I select the top five items with the most orders? I have an Item table, Order table, and many to many relationships between them.

Comment: I thought, you supposed to do the homework, not us. Tip - join, group by, count, limit

Comment: Please, remember to provide some code. That's the reason your're getting negative votes. Try it yourself, reading out on internet. And then come if you cannot. The community will be willing to help more and probably you will learn it.

Comment: My problem is that i didn't knew how to use JOIN properly now I understand, but thanks for your feedbacks, you guys have point, good day :)

Answer (score 0):

```
   SELECT COUNT(*) as total_order, item_name FROM `item_order` GROUP BY item_id ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 5
```

[image]